# Can not find sample of rate based performance counters

Tags: c#, .net, perfmon, performancecounter

We want to add some performance counters to our application, most of them need to reflect specific rates, such as number of security exceptions per hour, number of user logins per hour, number of application exceptions per 15 minutes. All samples online show how to do it per second, but we wnat to be able to do it over custom period (hour, minute etc).

It would be great if someone could show some code samples of how to do it. As far as I understand we need to create two counters: one to store totals and one to store time period.

Can anyone share some code of how to create rate based performance counters?